how to add genromfs package to my yocto project
I want to add the genromfs tool to my Yocto project, but I cannot find it on openembedded.org.
I checked the following link:
OpenEmbedded Layer Index
Could you please guide me on how to proceed with this modification?

You are refering to this repository, right?

In case there is no available recipe, you can create one:

Clone the code:
git clone https://github.com/chexum/genromfs.git

Use yocto recipetool (genromfs is the directory the cloned code is):
recipetool create -o genromfs.bb genromfs


Output:
# Recipe created by recipetool
# This is the basis of a recipe and may need further editing in order to be fully functional.
# (Feel free to remove these comments when editing.)

# WARNING: the following LICENSE and LIC_FILES_CHKSUM values are best guesses - it is
# your responsibility to verify that the values are complete and correct.
#
# The following license files were not able to be identified and are
# represented as "Unknown" below, you will need to check them yourself:
#   COPYING
LICENSE = "Unknown"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=0c56db0143f4f80c369ee3af7425af6e"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/chexum/genromfs.git;protocol=https;branch=master"

# Modify these as desired
PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "e4225b49a7be0ae9d39e98f2175dd674c0d6b1ea"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

# NOTE: this is a Makefile-only piece of software, so we cannot generate much of the
# recipe automatically - you will need to examine the Makefile yourself and ensure
# that the appropriate arguments are passed in.

do_configure () {
        # Specify any needed configure commands here
        :
}

do_compile () {
        # You will almost certainly need to add additional arguments here
        oe_runmake
}

do_install () {
        # This is a guess; additional arguments may be required
        oe_runmake install
}

